The gacha stamp collector’s problem
Just a fun problem I came up with.
Let $N \gg n \geq 2$ be natural numbers. In the Gacha stamp game, players are given an $N \times N$ square grid, with each point occupied by a unique stamp.
On every turn, they may choose a subsquare of size $n \times n$, and they are given uniformly at random a copy of one of the stamps from the subsquare.
Question: Under a strategy that is optimal for minimising the expected time taken, what is the expected time taken to get at least one of each stamp?
As detailed in the comments, the simple non-optimal strategy of filling in each square fully before moving on gives expected time $\sim N^2 \log n$. The exact result is actually $N^2 H_{n^2}$.
In any case, it is clear one cannot get better than $\Theta_n (N^2)$ with any strategy.
So the natural next question is whether one can improve the $\log n$ factor. Failing that, one can ask for precise constants, which I think is also interesting.

I don't know what is the optimal strategy, but there is a strategy that takes an expected time of $N^2H_n^2$, where $H_n$ is the harmonic sum upto $n$.

@YuzurihaInori $H_n$ being the harmonic number $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}$? Interesting…

It's a standard coupon collector argument. Although I did assume $n\mid N$. Do you mind the assumption? If you don't want the assumption, then there will be some ugly factors, but overall it would look like this really.

@Yuzuriha Inori Not at all, the problem is rather difficult so any simplying assumptions are more than welcome.

Would you mind sketching the strategy?

Sure. Break down your board into $n\times n$ sub-squares (There will be $(N/n)^2$ many such boards). For each sub-square, keep asking for that subsquare untill you have got all $n^2$ many unique stamps of that board. This takes expected time $n^2H_{n^2}$ (coupon collector). By linearity of expectation, the total expected time taken will be $(N/n)^2n^2H_{n^2}=N^2H_{n^2}$ (I had a little typo before :p). Asymptotically, this is $2N^2\ln(n)\sim \mathcal O(N^2)$ assuming $N>>n$.

Ah, so it is the naive strategy of filling up each square before moving on - even then one can get pretty decent asymptotics.

Asymptotically speaking, we cannot do better than this since we need to collect $N^2$ coupons. But maybe we can do better about the factors, but I don't really know.

Yes, see the comments i added to the original post for the natural next questions in my view. @YuzurihaInori
